# Magento 2: Is it possible to create conditional product options with Magento core functionality?

Tags: magento2, custom-options, magento-2.1, products, magento-2.1.1

I would like to be able to create several drop down options for certain products in the store. These options will show/hide based on the selected options on prior drop down field(s). Would this be possible with the core functionality that comes with Magento 2 (specifically version 2.1.1) or do I need to create a module or use 3rd party module to extend this functionality?

Thank you,

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: Two years later, were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to create a configurable product. see for example http://www.venustheme.com/how-to-create-configurable-product-magento-2/

Comment: Thank you for sharing. Based on the link you sent me, would it be possible to set up the condition in such way that if I select a size XL, the only color available are red and blue. ANy other sizes will have red, blue, white, green, yelllow?